# Union of a continuous sequence of sets

Tags: real-analysis

Given an sequence of sets represented as:
$$
E_t=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:f(x,t)\leq0\}
$$
For some $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ and $t\in[0,1]$. Let each $E_t$ be some closed and convex sets. Is there a way to represent the set
$$
\bar{E}=\bigcup_{t\in[0,1]} E_t
$$
As
$$
\bar{E}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:g(x)\leq0\}
$$
For some $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$? 
In other words, how can we compute $g(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been edited.

Yes. Take $g(x)=\sup_{t \in [0,1]} f(x,t)$